# make the child window appears in taskbar

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I make the child window appears in taskbar, in win32 program?
(the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` Extended Style, help only for top-level window)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to have a *child* window in the taskbar.  Perhaps you mean an *owned* window?

Comment: I write a word processor, with several files, that they ar child windows, and I want every file to be appear in the taskbar

Comment: It still doesn't really make sense for child windows.  What would selecting the taskbar item do?  Windows won't know which of your other child windows to hide or how to muck with your child windows' z-order.  Only your application knows how to do that.  And wouldn't it be more appropriate to give each document a separate taskbar thumbnail (like what IE does for separate tabs)?  Or if you really wanted, I suppose you could create hidden top-level windows that show the corresponding document when activated.

Comment: When I receive an activation message, I will change the Z order. and I wont the files be child windows, for their size will always be the parent client area size, and so they will use the parent window's menu.

Comment: But child windows can't get `WM_ACTIVATE` messages.  If you want to simulate child windows having corresponding top-level windows, then actually simulate that: make fake top-level windows that correspond to your child windows.

Comment: If you can show a child window on the taskbar, then certainly he gets a message when the user click on the button in the taskbar

Answer (score 1):

Normally only popup windows can appear in the task bar, but you may be able to use the `ITaskbarList` interface to do this.

According to the docs for `ITaskbarList::AddTab`,

> Any type of window can be added to the taskbar...

I've not tried this myself so I don't know if this will work with a child window but it's the only method I can think of that might be successful.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Comment: my program does not know the `ITaskbarList` interface, what code I need to add to use it?

Comment: You would need to create an instance using `CoCreateInstance` with CLSID_TaskbarList / IID_ITaskbarList.

Comment: I do not know COM, There is no API function for this ?